# PHP code not working how I'd like

Tags: php

I am creating a form where user can enter contact number and data is fetched from the database. now a same phone number can belongs to multiple people, this code is just fetching detail of one person at a time. what changes should i do so that it can fetch data for all the people.

```
<?php

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+/", $_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    //connect  to the database
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
    //-select  the database to use
    $mydb = mysql_select_db("trsv_data");


    //-query  the database table to find person_id
    $sql_search = "SELECT  person_id FROM contactnumbers WHERE contact_number = " . $name;
    // $sql_search="SELECT  person_id FROM Email WHERE Email LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' ";

    //-run  the query against the mysql query function
    $result = mysql_query($sql_search);
    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $person_id = $row['person_id'];
        //-display the result of the array
        echo "<ul>\n";
        //echo "Person Id: <a  href=\"trilliumsearch.php?id=$ID\">" . $person_id . "</a>\n";
        echo "Person Id: <a  href=\"person_search.php\">" . $person_id . "</a>\n";
        //http://localhost:8080/Trillium_Emarketing/Trillium/output/person_search.php
        echo "</ul>";


        //-query  the database table to find Person_FirstName
        $sql_Person = "SELECT  FirstName, company_id FROM person WHERE person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Person);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
            $company_id = $row['company_id'];
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>\n";
            echo "<b>First Name:</b> " . $FirstName;

        }


        //-query  the database table to find Person_MiddleName
        $sql_Person = "SELECT MiddleName FROM person WHERE person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Person);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $MiddleName = $row['MiddleName'];

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Middle Name:</b> " . $MiddleName;

        }

        //-query  the database table to find Person_LastName
        $sql_Person = "SELECT  LastName FROM person WHERE person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Person);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $LastName = $row['LastName'];

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Last Name:</b> " . $LastName;
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo "<p>";

        //-query  the database table to find Emails 
        $sql_Email = "SELECT  Email FROM email WHERE person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Email);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Email = $row['Email'];
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<b>Email: </b> " . $Email;

        }


        //-query  the database table to find Email_type
        $sql_Email = " SELECT Email_types FROM email_type,email WHERE email_type.email_type_id = email.email_type_id AND person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Email);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $Email_type = $row['Email_types'];

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Email Type: </b> " . $Email_type;

        }


        //-query  the database table to find Email_status
        $sql_Email = "SELECT email_status FROM email_status,email WHERE email_status.email_status_id = email.email_status_id AND person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_Email);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Email_status = $row['email_status'];
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Email Status:</b> " . $Email_status;
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo "<p>";

        //-query  the database table to find contact Number
        $sql_contactnumber = "SELECT  contact_number  FROM contactnumbers WHERE person_id =" . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_contactnumber);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $contact = $row['contact_number'];

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<b>Contact: </b>" . $contact;

        }

        //-query  the database table to find contact Number Type
        $sql_contactnumber = "SELECT contact_number_types FROM contact_number_types,contactnumbers WHERE contact_number_types.contact_num_types_id = contactnumbers.contact_num_type_id AND contactnumbers.person_id  = " . $person_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_contactnumber);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $contact_type = $row['contact_number_types'];
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Contact type: </b> " . $contact_type . "\n";
            echo "</ul> ";
        }
        echo "<p>";

        //-query  the database table to find Company
        $sql_company = "SELECT  company_name FROM company WHERE company_id =" . $company_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_company);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $company_name = $row['company_name'];

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<b>Company Name: </b>" . $company_name;

        }

        //-query  the database table to find Company Type
        $sql_company = "SELECT company_type FROM company_type,company WHERE company_type.company_type_id = company.company_type_id AND company_id =" . $company_id;

        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
        $result = mysql_query($sql_company);
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $company_type = $row['company_type'];
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo "<b>Company Type: </b>" . $company_type;
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        //-query  the database table to find Product blast

        $sql_product_blast = "SELECT product_name FROM product,product_blast WHERE product.product_id = product_blast.product_id AND product_blast.person_id =  " . $person_id;


        //-run  the query against the mysql query function

        $result = mysql_query($sql_product_blast);

        //-create  while loop and loop through result set

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];


            //-display the result of the array

            echo "<ul>\n";
            echo "<b>Product Blasted: </b>" . $product_name . "\n";
            echo "</ul>";

        }

    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). So sit back and relax. Someone will be along shortly to destroy your database and render your question moot.

Comment: none of my code does what i want, not once has at made coffee, or given be a back rub ;(

Comment: way to much code to narrow down the problem. Post code where you think or have an idea where the problem is occurring, this way we can understand and help you. Edit your question if you want help.

Comment: Also, do not use mysql_*functions they are no longer maintained.. use **PDO** or **mysqli_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, you are always use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` so you are always rewrite the `$result` and `$row`. So when you last call this, that will give you tha last row in your last loop, and in your main loop will terminated.

try this:

```
$sql_search = "SELECT  person_id FROM contactnumbers WHERE contact_number = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
$id_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_search);
while ($id_row = mysqli_fetch_array($id_result)) {
    //....
}
```

1) Avoid sql injections

2) Do not use mysql functions. Use mysqli or PDO functions instead of mysql_* functions.